# Можно ли в данном случае употребить название латиницей и как оформить?

Tags: кавычки, латиница-кириллица

Предложение такое:

*Пришлось поддерживать одной рукой другую, чтобы нажать «Enter».*

Можно ли так оформить название клавиши или лучше написать «Ввод»?

Comment: На вашем ПК есть клавиша «Ввод»? Тогда «Ввод».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно написать и латиницей, и кириллицей. Строгих правил оформления, насколько я знаю, нет. Вот что нашлось на Грамоте.ру:

> [**Вопрос № 294589**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
>
> Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли заключать в кавычки названия клавиш. Например, нажмите на кнопку «Продолжить» или нажмите клавишу «Enter» на клавиатуре. Спасибо.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Названия клавиш следует писать в кавычках. Однако **названия, написанные в русском тексте латиницей, в кавычки обычно не заключаются.** Корректно: *нажмите на кнопку «Продолжить» или клавишу Enter на клавиатуре.*

Отвечая на [**Вопрос № 289412**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9&start=0), Грамота пишет:

> Кавычки – выделительный знак, а написание латиницей в русском тексте само по себе является выделительным.

А далее, на этой же странице, отвечает на вопрос о правиле (№ 281354):

> Правила как такового нет: правила русского правописания не регламентируют написание названий, оформленных латиницей. Рекомендуя не заключать в кавычки подобные названия, мы руководствуемся здравым смыслом: написание латиницей в русском тексте само по себе является выделительным, зачем нужно дополнительное выделение кавычками?

Comment: Спасибо, пошла править.